# Word for small plastic takeaway cups for dressings, salsa, etc

Tags: single-word-requests, food

What is the name for the tiny clear takeaway/to-go cups with snap-on lids they give you at a restaurant for your entree's sauces?  The waitress told me like 10 times but I can't remember the next day.  I believe it would be a French derivation.  They are also used for samples at the grocery store.  One word.

[image: empty container]
[image: container with mustard]

Images from Amazon: [Crystalware, Disposable 1oz. Plastic Portion Cups with Lids, Condiment Cup, Jello Shot, Soufflé Portion, Sampling Cup, 100 Sets – Clear](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WDP5QS6).

Comment: This question sounds familiar; I think we have a duplicate.

Comment: Plastic Portion Cups with Lids, Condiment Cup, Jello Shot, Soufflé Portion, Sampling Cups?

Comment: "The waitress told me like 10 times but I can't remember." Tut tut.

Comment: Ew, salsa does not go in the same containers as half and half. Half & half containers have a foil lid and are not resealable. Thecontainers OP is asking about are unsuitable for liquids since the lid is not watertight (and the lid can be taken off and put back on again).

Comment: The word you're looking for may be *ramekin* (it's the only word I can think of for anything similar that's French).